# RestEasy - Unable to find MessageBodyReader ... application/xml?

Tags: wildfly, resteasy, java-ee-7

i try since 2 days to find something about this problem, still don't get it. I got my Maven-Project running on Wildfly.

Rest-Code:

```
@Override
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
//  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Customer getOverId(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        logger.info("put in " + this.getClass().getName() + " over id " + id);
//      if (id != null) {
//          Customer object = service.loadOneCustomer(new Integer(id));
//          logger.info("found in " + this.getClass().getName());
//          return Response.ok(object).build();
//      }
        Customer customer = service.loadOneCustomer(new Integer(id));
//      logger.info("nix found");
        if(customer == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("No customer found with the matching ID: " + id);
        }
        logger.info("Customer found: " + customer.getCustomerNumber());
//      return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        return customer;
    }
```

Client-Implementation:

```
public Response readCustomer(String id){
        log.info("Starting: Rest get a Customer with ID: " + id);
        log.info(this.URL);
        this.customerWebTarget = this.client.target(this.URL).path(id);
        Response response = this.customerWebTarget.request().buildGet().invoke();

//      TODO Customer cast application_xml auf Customer? Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);
        Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);

        log.info("Ending: Rest invoque a Customer with ID:" + customer.getCustomerNumber());
//      System.out.println("Ending: Rest get a Customer with ID: " + response.readEntity(String.class));

        return response;
    }
```

J-Unit Test:

```
@Test
    public void testGetCustomerById() throws Exception {

        Response response = this.customerRestClient.readCustomer("112");
        System.out.println("--->" + response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 200);
    }
```

Everything works perfekt till i try to get the Java-Object from the XML i get (Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);)

Am i missing something. I mean, i get read the xml-File and see every data in it... Why can't i cast it into Java-Object?

I always get this Error:

```
Javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MEssageBody of content-type-application/xml and type class de.....model.Customer
```

Comment: When posting code, please remove all statements and comments that only illustrate your trials and errors but do not help to explain the problem.

Comment: Since there is absolutely no reaction from Lycone I'll just add this comment for prosperity: one way to get this exception is when you try to serlalize a bean without a no-argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the `Customer` class, it's hard to tell, but most likely some or all JAXB annotations are missing. In particular, you'll need an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the Customer class please. Was it properly annotated?
Also add the @Produces back in.

Comment: This might be a comment, but no answer.

Comment: @hwellmann, dont have enough reputations to comment on the question :) & so posted as an answer.